# Android service - check if variable asynchronously changes over period of time?

Tags: java, android

Let's say I have a boolean isAction. In my service I want to run some sort of timer mechanism and if this boolean changes state, call some function X, else do nothing.

What would be the best way to do this? I've tried using timers to no avail, and I'm not sure if a handler with postDelayed would be appropriate to do this, since the boolean could change states back-and-forth, which may give me a "false-positive" of isAction never changing.

For more background info, an intent gets fired which starts a service. This service needs to determine if boolean isAction stays the same for about a second or so, and if it does, then take some action, else return and do nothing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently did a similar thing by storing the boolean in the shared preferences, i then implemented the registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener which will register a callback to be invoked when a change happens to the preference. have a look at the documentation for more info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Yep, that's quite the same solution. Oberser-Observable pattern, but this one is using the sharedPreferenceMechanism. That may give a lighter code as you wouldn't have to implement the source part of the event mechanism, but it can be ckind of akward as an architectural choice to always use SharedPreferences just to get notified of a property change...

Comment: True, but if its just one boolean your trying to keep track of then its definitely alot easier! I generally only use the Observer-Observable parttern when 

1. an abstraction has two aspects, one dependent on the other. Encapsulating these aspects in separate objects lets you vary and reuse them independently.
2. When a change to one object requires changing others, and you don't know how many objects need to be changed.
3. When an object should be able to notify other objects without making assumptions about who these objects are. In other words, you don't want these objects tightly coupled.

Answer (score 1):

You can't keep the service only waking up from times to times and checking the boolean value change. As you say it could give "false positive", not seeing any change if they occured twice.

The solution is to put in place a [observable-observer design pattern](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Design-Pattern/AsimpledemoofObservableandObserver.htm) that will fire an event when the boolean changes its value, and the service to register itself against the event source (the observable).

Hence there would be no need for a periodic check, the service would be aware of changes in the boolean value as soon as they would occur.

You could also put in place a direct method call to notify your service of a value change, but then it would mean that your service would always be started. That may be the case. In this situation, it would be better to bind your activity to the service and call its method through its IBinder interface.

Regards,
 Stéphane

stéphane